# Finding a username from Meteor.user().username and matching it to a different collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

Say I have a `Meteor.user()` object that looks like this:

```
{_id: "xxxxxxxx", username: "john"}
```

And I have a different collection, called `profiles`, that looks like this:

```
{_id: "yyyyyyy", username: "john", firstname: "John", lastname: "Doe", etc...}
```

Obviously, I was able to set the `username` property of `profiles` from `Meteor.user().username`.

However, when I try to match this info on the client:

```
import Profile form '../imports/api/profiles'

Template.AddInfo.helpers({
   interests(){
   return Profile.find({username: Meteor.user().username});
  }
});
```

and have this code in my jade template:

```
each interests
    p #{username}
```

nothing shows up.

Note: I've also tried `findOne({...})` as well with the same result.

What am I doing wrong here? Is it an issue with the way `Meteor.user()` is handled on the client?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you subscribe to the `Profile` collection ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't appear that you have subscribed to a publication which publishes `Profile` data.  Assuming that you are not using `autopublish`, then you must define a publish function on the server.

```
Meteor.publish("profiles", function () {
  return Profile.find({});
});
```

Then subscribe to this from your template from within your `onCreated` callback.

```
Template.AddInfo.onCreated(function() {
  this.subscribe('profiles');
});
```

Comment: Oh duh, you're right. Forgotten that I had removed `autopublish` from my packages file. Thanks!